# Oboe Fingerings in the Upper Register

Tags: fingering, oboe

Does anyone have a trick for playing notes like high E (three ledger lines above the staff) with all of those lovely pinky keys?  My current technique is button mashing and hoping for the best, but that is not sustainable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really helps to keep your left pinky curved and hovering close to all the pinky keys in the left hand.  (Keeping your fingers curved and close to all the keys is really a great way to gain better technique and speed.)  Trying to mash Eb and Ab with a flat pinky finger can lead to some discomfort and bad technique.  If you want to spice up your options, you can always play left Eb and right Ab, or left Ab and right Eb, but, really, it's standard to play both with the left hand.  Also, check your high E with a tuner.  If you find yourself to be ridiculously sharp, try only pushing Ab instead of both.  This will help lower the pitch.

Hope this helps!